# Validation between a text field and number field

Tags: validation

Validation between two text fields for entry
I have a business case where our back office team enters state witholding information. Some states use letters (A-F) and some use numbers. I have both fields built but I want validation that makes it possible that if a letter is entered in the letter field that a number cannot be entered in the number field.

Comment: Trailhead has a solid [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/point_click_business_logic/units/validation_rules) on validation rules, which is the functionality you need to make this possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's as simple as:

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Text_Field__c)) && NOT(ISBLANK(Number_Field__c))
```

If both fields are not blank, then display an error. As an alternative, you can also write:

```
NOT(ISBLANK(Text_Field__c) || ISBLANK(Text_Field__c))
```

Which uses something known as "[De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)": `NOT A AND NOT B` can be written as `NOT (A OR B)`, and `NOT A OR NOT B` can be written as `NOT (A AND B)`.